# Google Maps v3 - prevent API from loading Roboto font

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google adds styles to the maps container that override my styles.
I know how to fix this. But the API (v3.8/9/exp) also loads the webfont "Roboto" which I don't really need/want.

Is there any setting/option/way around this?
Can I prevent the API from adding the extra CSS?

This is the code the google-maps-API adds to the `<head>` of my page:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .gm-style .gm-style-cc span,
  .gm-style .gm-style-cc a,
  .gm-style .gm-style-mtc div {
    font-size:10px
  }
</style>

<link type="text/css" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">

<style type="text/css">
  @media print {
    .gm-style .gmnoprint,
    .gmnoprint {
      display:none
    }
  }
  @media screen {
   .gm-style .gmnoscreen,
   .gmnoscreen {
     display:none
   }
  }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
  .gm-style {
    font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Is that the output?  It's hard to tell what the code itself is referencing.

Comment: @JoshBurgess yep, this is what google adds to the `<head>` when including the maps-api-javascript

Comment: Short of using an older version of the gmapsAPI, I can't find a way to prevent Roboto from coming over without blocking requests to that domain from Apache, IIS or whatever equivalent you're using.  If that's enough, I'll pop it into an answer, but it seems like a cop-out to me.

Comment: @pkyeck, check it out! is working!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can replace the insertBefore method before the Google script invokes it:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/7st6d9p2/

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

// Save the original method
var insertBefore = head.insertBefore;

// Replace it!
head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {

    if (newElement.href && newElement.href.indexOf('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto') > -1) {

        console.info('Prevented Roboto from loading!');
        return;
    }

    insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
};

// Check it!
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center           : new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom             : 16,
    mapTypeId        : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl      : false,
    panControl       : false,
    mapTypeControl   : false
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. was hoping for some kind of API-option you could use but this 'hack' definitely works :)

Comment: I haven't found anything on their docs, guess that they want to preserve its style. Btw, once the font load is prevented, you can revert the change to skip that if on each insertBefore call.

Comment: Great Thanks! Works for me.

Comment: This is nice and clever. I'm not sure to understand: does the solution replace the `insertBefore` method specifically for the `<head>` tag?

I think I need some explanations about the `insertBefore.call(head, newEl, refEl);` : is this syntax used to make sure we call here the standard ìnsertBefore` , or for another reason?

And about the `var insertBefore = head.insertBefore;` : I don't understand what is used for.

Thanks in advance, I'm trying to understand. :)

Comment: hey @meduz'!, yes, the idea is monkey patching the insertBefore method only for the head DOM node: http://me.dt.in.th/page/JavaScript-override/

Comment: OK I see. Thank you!

Comment: For guys without SSL (https), use http in the link for this to work.

Comment: @AymanSalah or just use `newElement.href.indexOf('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto') !== -1` which works for both http and https

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the map is embedded using an iframe, because the Roboto font is loaded by a css call in the head section of the iframe document, to which access is prevented. Any hint on that?

Comment: Works great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE 10/2017**

Google changed the approach of how they inject the styles on the page. Currently they inserting an empty `style` element and then changing the contents of this style element with Robot font. Here is a new solution:

```
// Preventing the Google Maps libary from downloading an extra font
(function() {
    var isRobotoStyle = function (element) {

        // roboto font download
        if (element.href
            && element.href.indexOf('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto') === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        // roboto style elements
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'style'
            && element.styleSheet
            && element.styleSheet.cssText
            && element.styleSheet.cssText.replace('\r\n', '').indexOf('.gm-style') === 0) {
            element.styleSheet.cssText = '';
            return true;
        }
        // roboto style elements for other browsers
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'style'
            && element.innerHTML
            && element.innerHTML.replace('\r\n', '').indexOf('.gm-style') === 0) {
            element.innerHTML = '';
            return true;
        }
        // when google tries to add empty style
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'style'
            && !element.styleSheet && !element.innerHTML) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // we override these methods only for one particular head element
    // default methods for other elements are not affected
    var head = $('head')[0];

    var insertBefore = head.insertBefore;
    head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {
        if (!isRobotoStyle(newElement)) {
            insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
        }
    };

    var appendChild = head.appendChild;
    head.appendChild = function (textNode) {
        if (!isRobotoStyle($(textNode)[0])) {
            appendChild.call(head, textNode);
        }
    };
})();
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Thanks to **coma** for the solution! I also decided to intercept styles which override the font-family, font-size and font-weight. The complete solution for modern browsers and IE8+:

```
// Preventing the Google Maps libary from downloading an extra font
var head = $('head')[0];
var insertBefore = head.insertBefore;
head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {
    // intercept font download
    if (newElement.href
        && newElement.href.indexOf('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto') === 0) {
        return;
    }
    // intercept style elements for IEs
    if (newElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'style'
        && newElement.styleSheet
        && newElement.styleSheet.cssText
        && newElement.styleSheet.cssText.replace('\r\n', '').indexOf('.gm-style') === 0) {
        return;
    }
    // intercept style elements for other browsers
    if (newElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'style'
        && newElement.innerHTML
        && newElement.innerHTML.replace('\r\n', '').indexOf('.gm-style') === 0) {
        return;
    }
    insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
};
```

Comment: Magnificent, thanks a lot. You can easily leave out the 2 jQuery references, so it's usable by anyone:

`document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` instead of `$('head')[0];`
`textNode` instead of `$(textNode)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

For TypeScript a solution would be:

```
const head = document.head;
const insertBefore = head.insertBefore;
head.insertBefore = <T extends Node>(
  newElement: T,
  referenceElement: Node
): T => {
  if (
    newElement instanceof Element &&
    newElement?.hasAttribute('href') &&
    newElement?.getAttribute('href')?.includes('fonts.googleapis')
  ) {
    return newElement;
  }

  insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
  return newElement;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found above solution to prevent websites with Google Maps from loading Roboto.

If you - like I do - use Wordpress, there might be other plugins referring to Google Fonts.

However, I struggled on some of my websites with the above code, since parts of it (1) affected also other styles to load, (2) "killed" styles, which intentionally not only contained gm-style, but other styles as well and (3) not affected other Google Fonts to load, where one or another plugin added links to fonts.googleapis.com by DOM-manipulation as well.

The below worked for me. It simply prevents other scripts from adding any tag having https://fonts.googleapis.com in it's href-attribute.

```
(function($) {
var isGoogleFont = function (element) {
    // google font download
    if (element.href
        && element.href.indexOf('https://fonts.googleapis.com') === 0) {
        return true;
    }       
    return false;
}

// we override these methods only for one particular head element
// default methods for other elements are not affected
var head = $('head')[0];

var insertBefore = head.insertBefore;
head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {
    if (!isGoogleFont(newElement)) {
        insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
    }
};

var appendChild = head.appendChild;
head.appendChild = function (textNode) {
    if (!isGoogleFont($(textNode)[0])) {
        appendChild.call(head, textNode);
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your code. Unfortunately I can't manage to get this to work. When I add it to the functions.php file of my child theme it says: "syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)" and I can't save the file.

Any idea why it doesn't accept $?

Comment: @Mario Add `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` to the top and that should fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm a newb and I couldn't get the other suggestions to work. So I removed all the Google fonts from the DOM. I hope it helps.

```
const googleFont = document.querySelector('link[rel="stylesheet"][href*="fonts.googleapis.com"]');
    if (googleFont) {
      googleFont.remove();
    }
```