# How to disable Google Fonts from Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization, font-face, google-font-api

I am working with Google Charts and customizing design for making it more beautiful.

But on embedding font faces in the Google Charts, I am getting an error within the Firebug console, which I am unable to understand. Firebug shows this error:

> "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request -
>   http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=hand_of_seanregular%7CInterstateRegular%7CInterstateRegular%7CInterstateRegular%7CInterstateRegular"

Good news is that the font is visible. From the error I think it's forcing the font to be a Google font but I am using a font face.

What I am writing is this:

```
textStyle : { 
    color: '#fff',
    fontName: "InterstateRegular",
    fontSize: 16,
    bold: false,
},
```

Could anyone tell me what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Interstate is not a web safe font (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web-safe_fonts) and won't be visible for the majority of users. I suggest you select a font which is available on Google Fonts (https://www.google.com/fonts), which solves your error and makes your chart look like intended on all/most clients.

Comment: @udondan Can't we use Embedded Font Face in Google Charts for it? Is it compulsory to use Google Font only?

Answer (score 1):

webfont.js seems to call insertBefore() which in turn loads a Google Font. So the solution is to override the default insertBefore() function, look for href string that matches the one giving you an error and then return early - otherwise call the default insertBefore()

Code here: [Google Maps v3 - prevent API from loading Roboto font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523806/google-maps-v3-prevent-api-from-loading-roboto-font)