# Google PageSpeed Insights Claims I'm Loading Font Not Used by Website

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I'm spent the last few days optimizing CSS and Javascript delivery for our website. We improved it to 86, but are having issues with Google Fonts. PageSpeed insights claims we are loading a font called Roboto. I can do a Find All across our entire coding directory and there is not one mention of the word 'Roboto'. We are not using the font.

Our 'Consider Fixing' section is as follows:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in
>   above-the-fold content Your page has 1 blocking script resources and 3
>   blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
>   None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered
>   without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or
>   asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical
>   portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
>
> Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
>
> - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900
> - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700

I experimenting with different loading techniques for Lato (importing, loading async via javascript file), but loading via a link in the header was the fastest method by 10 points. I'm worried Roboto could be affecting our score and is somehow slowing down our site.

Any idea why PageInsights says it is being loaded? If it is being loaded somehow, how can I track that code down?

EDIT: Here is a link to the site
http://www.triphappy.com/

Comment: @Paulie_D - Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question to add a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, the first line in your `<head>` tag is....

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing that? Screenshot of my source code:
http://i.imgur.com/RxkOTzJ.png

Comment: Added image...perhaps you have a plugin or widget that's adding the link and additional styles via JS?

Comment: Interesting, you have the link to the font and 4 style tags that I do not have. It appears this is a font google maps loads automatically, and other people have had problems with as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523806/google-maps-v3-prevent-api-from-loading-roboto-font

I wonder why it is not showing up in my source code? Anyways, thanks for the help and I'm glad its not as stupid as I initially thought.

Comment: I have the same issue in PageSpeed. It is weird that it is registered as blocking css, when the js file that sets that block in the header is async....