# How to prevent Google captcha from downloading Roboto

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, recaptcha

So I've been looking for a way to block any request to fonts.gstatic.com since it's not allowed in Germany. I'm using Vue 2 with [Vue recaptcha](https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha)

I've found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35993046/8590102 but unfortunately it's not working since I don't have any element.href in my head element. The only thing is:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vueRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer> </script>`

Is there any other way I can stop any request to the google api?

Comment: Legal reference in Deutsch and English: [LG München, Urteil vom 19.01.2022, Az. 3 O 17493/20](https://rewis.io/urteile/urteil/lhm-20-01-2022-3-o-1749320/) "The use of external font services cannot be based on [the] GDPR, since the use of the fonts is also possible without a connection from visitors to external servers."

Comment: From what I've read, the only solution is to use a different non-Google captcha.  The complaint about the fonts started years ago because Google automatically downloads 100k of data, but it has since become a GDPR issue about sharing user IP with 3rd parties.  It's the kind of question I would kick to our legal department for direction.

Comment: That's the problem. They want to keep that captcha :(

Comment: This one couldn't be a replacement? https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-turnstile It's a captcha at the end of the day, has one job whatever you're using exactly.

Comment: Otherwise, you could [load them at build time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166329/8816585) or even host them yourself with the following: https://github.com/majodev/google-webfonts-helper

Comment: If this is a European website then it mostly likely has a TOS notification that visitors must agree to by clicking.  And it may be enough to add a notification to the TOS that the user's IP may be shared with 3rd parties. Yet, this is why it's important to get guidance from the legal department and have everything documented. Our job as programmers is limited to finding technical, and not legal, solutions to problems, eh?